# DISTINCT SQL query in apache drill using elasticsearch plugin returns codegeneration error

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-drill

The below sql query in apache drill which uses elastic search plugin returns the following error. and this seems to be happening only for string columns.

```
select distinct(STRING_BASED_ID) from es_index_name limit 1;
```

Error: EXECUTION_ERROR ERROR: Exception happened when executing generated code

Open failed for reader: EnumerableRecordReader
Fragment: 0:0

[Error Id: c9d0aff7-65c5-4079-b037-4e93b6152c4d on ****servers:31010] (state=,code=0)

Comment: Would you mind please posting this issue on Drill's github?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the whole stack trace, it is possible that the actual reason is shown at the bottom, I think there is something like no such field for that table.

Comment: Update: error message was fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-8002